# two sample t-test (t_value) in r

Tags: r

```
machine1 <- c(30.02,29.99,30.11,29.97,30.01,29.99)
machine2 <- c(29.89,29.93,29.97,29.98,30.02,29.98)

t.test(machine1,machine2, var.equal = TRUE, paried = FALSE)
```

When I run this code,

```
Two Sample t-test

data:  machine1 and machine2
t = 1.9417, df = 10, p-value = 0.08085
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.007867295  0.114533962
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 30.01500  29.96167
```

I got this result.

But when I tried to calculate t-statistic manually, it's different.

What I got is

```
s^2 = 0.0023
s = 0.048
t = (30.015-29.962) / 0.048 * sqrt(1/10 + 1/10) = 0.053/0.021 = 2.4

calculated by R = 1.9417
calculated by myself = 2.4
```

Which part did I do incorrectly?

Thanks for the advices in advance

Comment: You write `t = (30.015-29.962) / 0.048 * sqrt(1/10 + 1/10) = 0.053/0.021 = 2.4` which is the same as writing `t = 2.4` since the `2.4` overwrites `0.053/021` which overwrites `(30.015-29.962) / 0.048 * sqrt(1/10 + 1/10)` but these things are not equal. `(30.015-29.962) / 0.048 * sqrt(1/10 + 1/10)` equals ~0.494 and `0.053/0.021` equals ~2.52

Comment: you also have a typo in your `t.test()` code - paired / paried

Comment: @jpsmith Thank you for the reply! 
the t = ~~~ is how I calculated manually :) ( not code ) 
I just don't understand why the result is different :(

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen Thank you for the comment! 

I fixed it ! but the result is still different :( 
any advice please?

Thanks

Comment: I think you meant to type (30.015-29.962) / (0.048 * sqrt(1/10 + 1/10))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code to compute the pooled standard error from `t.test`, slightly simplified:

```r
nx <- length(machine1); ny <- length(machine2)
vx <- var(machine1); vy <- var(machine2)
df <- nx + ny - 2
v <- (nx - 1) * vx + (ny - 1) * vy
v <- v/df
stderr <- sqrt(v * (1/nx + 1/ny))
```

This comes out to 0.0274 rather than 0.021.

```r
(mean(machine1)-mean(machine2))/0.0274
```

is 1.9464.

Not quite sure what's going on here except that there may be some significant effects of roundoff error?

Comment: Thank you for the answer!! 

I think there was my mistake when I calculated since the formula is same!! 

I agree with you I think there may be some roundoff error :) 

Thank you again

Comment: If you compute `(mean(machine1)-mean(machine2))/stderr` the result and `t.test(..)$statistic` compare `TRUE` with `==`. Apart from the data names, even your notation is equal to the notation in `t.test.default`.